# Duplicated being added to list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have class MySet that I want to return the elements in both seta and setb. However, it returns that element twice.

```
class MySet:
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.elements=elements
    def intersection(self, other_set):
        new_set = list(self.elements)
        for j in other_set:
            if j in self.elements:
                new_set.append(j)
        for h in self.elements:
            if h not in other_set:
                new_set.remove(h)
        new_set.sort()
        return new_set
```

So if `seta=MySet([1,2,3])` and `setb=MySet([1,5,6])`, `setc=seta.intersection(setb.elements)`, doing `print(setc)` should give `[1]` but instead gives `[1,1]`. How can I fix this? Also, is there anyway to do `setc=seta.intersection(setb)`, without the `.elements`? Thank you.

Comment: This is what adds it twice: `if j in self.elements: new_set.append(j)`. Of course, you could just use: `return sorted(set(self.elements) & set(other_set))` (-;

Comment: You are initializing `new_set = list(self.elements)` and *then* you append *more* to it. You want to initialize it to an empty list, and only append if they're in both objects.

Comment: Thank you. I realized I didn't need the remove part of the function, which is why I had trouble creating an empty list in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns a list of only the values shared between the two sets.

```
class MySet:
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.elements=elements
    def intersection(self, other_set):
        return sorted(set(self.elements) & set(other_set))
seta=MySet([1,2,3])
setb=MySet([1,5,6])

setc=seta.intersection(setb.elements)
print(setc)
```

The reason why your code was providing [1,1] with your given inputs was that you were appending matches to new_list, instead of simply removing non-matches.

There are ways to get out of typing .elements by playing around with **repr** and similar for your class.

Comment: Thank you, Would you be able to elaborate exactly how I would do that in __repr__?